# pad block corrupted?

Tags: android, cryptography

I have been using the following two methods to encrypt and decrypt sensitive info.

```
public static String encryptSensitiveInfo(String strToEncrypt,
                                          String saltToEncrypt) throws Exception {

    String encryptedString = "";
    byte[] encryptedValue;

    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(saltToEncrypt.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    encryptedValue = cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes());
    encryptedString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedValue));

    encryptedValue = null;
    return encryptedString;
}



public static String decryptSensitiveInfo(String strToDecrypt,
                                          String saltToDecrypt) throws Exception {

    String decryptedString = "";
    byte[] decryptedValue;

    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(saltToDecrypt.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    decryptedValue = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt
            .getBytes()));
    decryptedString = new String(decryptedValue);

    decryptedValue = null;
    return decryptedString;
}
```

At the time of decryption I get "pad block corrupted" execption. Any help to resolve this issue would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560461/decryption-error-pad-block-corrupted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decryption Error: Pad block corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560461/decryption-error-pad-block-corrupted)

Comment: @crammeur - Thanks. Will take a look. This decryption have been creeping up off late and throws up once in a blue moon

Comment: `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` don't do this. Always specify the full *algorithm/mode/padding* transformation string. Also, there is no Base64 class in android that has the methods you are using. You need to tell us what software you are using.

Comment: Hello James, I'm using this in my android code. Ain't using any specific software

Comment: `decodeBase64` uses Apache Commons Codec.. I would call that "specific software".

Comment: **Warning**: The code above is clearly not secure. It uses ECB mode to encrypt data and it relies on the default character encoding, to name just two issues.

Answer (score 0):

You're correctly performing base 64 on the ciphertext because the ciphertext consists of random looking bytes. However, you forget to do the same with your key (which, inexplicably, is called `saltToDecrypt` in your code). If the keys do not match or if the ciphertext has become corrupted then you will almost certainly run into a `BadPaddingException`.

If the amount of ciphertext has changed an `IllegalBlockSizeException` is more likely and if the key isn't of the right size for AES, an `InvalidKeyException`.